# c# mock object with private constructor, initialized via a static factory method

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I am testing the following controller:

```
public class MyController : ApiController
{
    private readonly IUserManager _users;
    private int num = 0;

    public MyController(IUserManager users)
    {
        _users = users;
    }

    public User GetByCredentials(string username, string pass)
    {
        var account = new Account(username, pass);          
        User u = _users.GetByCredentials(num, account);
        return u;
    }
```

I was thinking to mock the *IUserManager.GetByCredentials* method, as I only want to see that *MyController.GetByCredentials* method works as expected. The problem is that the *User* class cannot be instantiated directly, so I cannot mock a User object, because the constructor is private:

```
public class User
{
    // private attributes here

    protected User()
    {
        // do a lot of stuff here, call other objects to initialize attributes
    }

    private User(int num, string id, string userid, Account account)
        : this()
    {
       // do other stuff here with the params
    }


    public static User CreateUser(int num, string id, string userid, Account account)
    {
        return new User(num, id, userid, account);
    }
    // and so on

}
```

I am using the Moq framework, but I am open to different solutions. I would prefer to avoid the creation of test data in this case, because it depends on database the initialization, servers and so on - and then it would not be a unit test anymore. Have you ever had an issue like this? How do you deal with it? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to mock `User` - you can use the real `User` class. You only need to mock (or fake) `IUserManager`. Your mock/fake `IUserManager` can use `User.CreateUser` to create the `User` objects to be returned to your controller.

Unless the `User` class itself "knows" about the database, that should be fine. Resist the temptation to mock *everything* - you only need to get rid of dependencies that make it hard to write tests.

Now you've written that your `User` private constructor "does a lot of stuff" - if that reaches out too far, you should redesign `User` so it's simpler... your user *manager* should possibly be responsible for some of the work that's going on there.

While it's an oversimplification to completely split the world into services (like the user manager) and dumb data objects (like the user), it makes things much easier if a design reasonably *naturally* splits itself in that respect.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have added a comment to the previous one, and I guess that the only way to go is by refactoring that code... damn it :S

Comment: @Markon: Fundamentally, when you've got untestable code, the right way to go *is* to refactor it. I mean, you could create an `IUser` interface and mock *that* instead, but it really sounds like the mess in `User` should be resolved.

Answer (score 3):

In order to test your `MyController`, you will be mocking `IUserManager` not `User` so you will be able to do something like this:

```
var mockUserManager = new Mock<IUserManager>();

// Configure the User to be returned by calling GetByCredentials
mockUserManager
    .Setup(x => x.GetByCredentials(It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<Account>())
    .Returns(User.CreateUser(1, "foo", "username", new Account());

var controller = new MyController(mockUserManager.Object);

var user = controller.GetByCredentials("username", "password");

Assert.NotNull(user);

mockUserManager.Verify(x => x.GetByCredentials(It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<Account>(), Times.Once());
```

The point of mock/fake objects is to avoid database/web service calls. Your `Account` and `User` classes should be poco classes - e.g. only contain methods and properties which act upon itself, no database or web service calls etc so they don't actually need mocking.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I am doing - mocking the IUserManager, but unfortunately the User.CreateUser method is invoking database/servers to get configurations and so forth. Yes, I know, it's kind of bad design, and this must be refactored by using dependency injection on the User (so that I can mock database and everything else), but I was wondering if there is an "easier" way.

Comment: You could create an IUser interface from the User class which you return from IUserManager and then also mock that but you'd be better off removing the database code from the static method as you already mentioned.